# Chat message search: Show user Gravatar in auto complete list when searching

Tags: feature-request, chat, profile-picture, chat-search

Right now, the search functionality has an option to search for messages said by only one user. When typing in the username, you get an autocomplete list like:

[image]

As you can see, there are four people with just the name `merlin` (although three have an uppercase `M`). It is impossible to distinguish which is the merlin you want to search for, as they all look the same. There is no method of knowing which Merlin corresponds to which account from the dropdown in the list.

Could we have a small avatar shown next to each name, so that it is easily distinguishable as to which account is on the list?