# Show profile picture in chat autocomplete

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

On the same note as [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168994/chat-message-search-show-user-gravatar-in-auto-complete-list-when-searching) to show profile pictures when drilling down to a specific user in search, it'd be swell if the chat @ autocomplete could show a tiny profile picture next to each person's name.

[image]

It'd also be neat if the superping menu had this too.

An alternative for fixing my root issue (confusion when pinging co-workers) would be to stop hiring people named "Ben" or "Jon", but I think *technically* that falls under "discrimination".

Comment: I was the first Ben, so I'm okay with that.

Comment: Or alternatively, we can just rename all the Bens and Jons to Kasra. We can never have enough Kasras.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here you go:

[image: screenshot of the new tab completer including avatars]

I've made multiple improvements to the tab autocompleter:

- The autocompleter now shows avatars.
- The autocompleter now shows the user name including spaces (small change, but it looks nicer). The actually inserted name will still be stripped of spaces, of course.
- The people that show up in the autocompleter and the people that can be notified with a @mention are now in sync. That's of course a reasonable expectation to have, but it [hasn't been true so far](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78625/115866). If you can ping someone with a mention in the current room (the rules of which [can be found here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/938/what-are-the-rules-for-when-chat-messages-appear-in-a-users-inbox/939#939)), they will show up (unless you have them in your ignore list), and if you can't, they won't.
- We now show more matches (up to ten instead of five).
- When you have multiple matches and you cycle through them with the tab key (or by clicking), we no longer use bolding to highlight the current choice (which would always cause things to jump around, since bold text is much wider).
- It's a little prettier. I think so, anyway.

Comment: That's *awesome.*

Comment: Those are some fine looking people you are potentially going to ping.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmzyYquMS2I

Comment: This is all nice and great, but why did you have to change your undocumented API that my userscript depends on in the process?

Comment: @JanDvorak That's more of your fault for relying on some random API that nobody except balpha probably knows about anyway, isn't it? :)

Comment: @Doorknob well, you have to rely on something, and this seemed like as good a choice as any

Comment: @JanDvorak Because the old one sucked big time :) Feel free to ping me in the Tavern if you have concrete questions (as long as you don't take me answering them as official support).

Comment: Two additional requests while the code is fresh: moderator super pings and ["when said by" in search](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search) could also benefit from having avatars. I suppose that's a lot more images that would need to be fetched, so it might be slow. But that's ok since both are pretty rare. (But having a way to distinguish between identical display names is especially useful in both cases.)

Comment: @JonEricson Yes, Kasra mentions that in the question as well, I plan to do that too. That code isn't fresh though, it's an entirely different area :) Although I'd like to improve the superping UI to work more like the autocomplete, if I can work out an intuitive way to do that. Either way, status-planned.