# In the chat's @name autocomplete, a user is showing up with two avatars

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, autocomplete

So, this suggestion just got implemented: [Show profile picture in chat autocomplete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239590/152515)

That is *very cool,* and I'm happy with it. However, there's a chat user who has the special privilege of showing up with *two avatars* in the autocomplete suggestions [in the RPG Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat):

[image: Mourdos, specifically, is that person]

I suspect this is a bug.

The above screenshot was with Windows 8 Firefox Aurora 34.02a, but others in the same room confirm it, including users of OS X Chrome 37.0.02 and Linux Chromium.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are *two* users with that name*. And when two users have the same name and are pingable in the room, then you can't ping one without pinging the other. And that's why in such a case, both avatars will appear inside the same autocomplete element.

To be precise, they don't need *exactly* the same user name, as long as the normalized version used for matching is identical (lowercasing, remove spaces, normalize diacritics). For example, three users with the names "John Nyman", "jöhnnyMÁN", and "Johnny Man" would also appear inside the same element. The name version that appears in that element is the name of the user with the first avatar (which is the user that *would* appear first in the list, if they were displayed separately, which in turn is the user who spoke most recently).

<sub>* They are clearly both the same person, and their parent users have already been merged. I'll do that in chat as well after this.</sub>

Comment: That'd explain it. I'm okay with those avatars showing up together if there's multiple users who'll all get pinged at once - no point making their name show up multiple times too. Thanks!

Comment: "And when two users have the same name and are pingable in the room, then you can't ping one without pinging the other." – Unless you're a moderator, in which case you can ["superping"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258038/335251) a specific user by ID (regardless of whether they've been in that chat room). :)