# User has two gravatars in name autocomplete

Tags: bug, chat, account-suspension

I just decided to ping a suspended (isn't relevant) user:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And their gravatar appears twice in the name autocomplete.

---

It turns out "*the bug is a zombie chat profile that isn't deleted even long days after its parent account is deleted*" ~ [Shadow Wizard](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3455776#3455776)

I.E. here is the [chat profile](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/288071/nicael), but the [linked account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/288071/nicael) is deleted (404).

Comment: Because he's at least twice as much trouble as the rest of us.

Comment: Got nothing to do with suspension, this time. :)

Comment: For general reference, this is expected: [In the chat's @name autocomplete, a user is showing up with two avatars](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240080) (but obviously the chat users should be merged/one deleted in this specific case)